# How to accept the value as UTC?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, utc, gmt

Using MomentJS + ReactJS: Currently I have the following but it accepts the value as local time.

How can I have it accept the value as UTC date/time and not local date/time?

```
var dateTime = new Date("11 30 2016 00:00:00")
//Logs as: `Wed Nov 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)` but would want it to just accept the value as is in GMT/UTC rather than PST, local date/time/
```

Will be sure to upvote. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new native javascript Date object instead of a "Moment" instance.

Since you're using Moment, you probably want to use `moment.utc()` instead. There is [documentation here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) on the method.

In your instance:

`var time = moment.utc("11-30-2016 00:00:00");`

Comment: I recall being able to do like new Date("..." + "UTC"), do you know which I'm referring to?

Comment: Actually gave what you suggested a try, and it console logged the following: `1480464000000`. I would like it to return `Wed Nov 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT` rather, and not in PST.

Comment: You can use `time.toString()` to get it in that format. You can sometimes use `new Date('...' + 'Z')` to set it to UTC (Zulu) time, but that doesn't work in all browsers.